# Sending List of objects to Rest service in Java

Tags: java, list, rest, jax-rs, jersey-2.0

I have a rest api that looks like this

```
    @POST
    @Path("/cities")
    @Consumes({ MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON, MediaType.APPLICATION_XML })
    public Response createCity(City city) {
    }
```

Above is working fine.Now I want to have another service that accepts List of Cities. Then I created a wrapper object which has List of cities field, something like this

```
 @XmlRootElement
    public class CityHolder {

        List<City> cities;
      ....................

   @POST
    @Path("/cities/list")
    @Consumes({ MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON, MediaType.APPLICATION_XML })
    public Response createCities(CityHolder cityHolder) {
    }
```

Above worked fine for me.
I tried below also

```
        @POST
        @Path("/cities/list")
        @Consumes({ MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON, MediaType.APPLICATION_XML })
        public Response createCities(List<City> cityList) {
        }
```

which works fine as well.
Can someone let me know what's the best practice to send the list of objects.

Comment: Can you elaborate on _"doesn't work"_?

Comment: Updated..actually both worked..only thing is that which one is better

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say if you only want to send the list, use a list of objects. If you want to send additional hints with the list, use a wrapped object.

In your case, I would prefer the list ifself.

Hope it helps,
Thierry